# How to system know that one over of cricket has 6 balls (Calculation) in Android

Tags: android, algorithm, arithmetic-expressions

I'm developing a cricket app and I'm getting problems when I'm working with overs. We all know that whatever calculation is done in calculator is done with 10.

For example :

If there are total overs : 20, and current over 2.1
And I want to calculate remaining overs.

So the formula would be : (total overs - current overs)

The answer should be  17.5

But I'm getting the answer as 17.9

Same thing occurrs in run rate and required run rate.

What I'm actually doing wrong?? Anyone has some algorithm or formula or any code that can convert convert overs like this.

Thanks.

Comment: Android is an OS, what is the language you are using?  C++, C#, something else?

Comment: You're expecting base 10 arithmetic to operate like the rules of cricket - that's what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Neil I'm using Java

Comment: `What I'm actually doing wrong?` You're not pasting your code and your error log. Asking for an algorythm is conceptually wrong, here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float total=total-0.4;
float current;
float remaining=total-current;
```

Comment: It is returning me my old answer

Comment: Try again.. let total=20, current=2.1 so m=0.1 and remaning=(20-2)-0.5=17.5

Comment: if total = 20 and current = 20 the above gives -0.6 remaining. After 1 over it gives 18.4

Comment: There are only 6 balls in an over. So max current could be 19.6

Comment: no the maximum is 20 overs nobody says 19 overs and 6 balls.

Comment: Okay then 20 overs will have 20*6=120 balls so 19.6 overs will have 19*6+6=120 balls too. How?

Comment: @pranav last over will also have 6 balls so why are you counting 10

Comment: but @Akshay in cricket no one says its 19.6, we've to display 20 instead of 19.6

Answer (score 0):

```
public class T {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberOfBalls=34;
        String round = String.valueOf(Math.round(numberOfBalls / 6));
        String mod=String.valueOf(numberOfBalls%6);
        double numberOfOvers=Double.valueOf(round+"."+mod);
        System.out.println(numberOfOvers);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This shall help you:

```
 public float GetOversLeft(){


        var tempOversLeft = TotalOvers % 6;
        var totalBallsLeftInANOver = ((TotalOVers - currentBallNumber) % 6) /10;


         return tempOversLeft + totalBallsLeftInANOver;


    }

    public int GetTotalBallsLeftInOver(){

    var tempBallsLeft=  (int) (  ((TotalBallsInMatch - currentBallNumber)%6));
    if(tempBallsLeft== 0){
        tempBallsLeft= 6;
    }

    return tempBallsLeft;




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting over from total balls delivered

```
public function calculation_over()
{
    $balls = 80;
    $balls2 = 80;
    $balls -= $balls % 6;
    $total_overs = $balls / 6;
    $f = $balls2 % 6;
    echo $total_overs_calculated = (float)$total_overs.'.'.$f;
}
```

if total balls delivered is 80 balls then first we have to make it divisible by 6 then we get 78 from ($balls -= $balls % 6;) then it will we divided by 6 then we get 13 means 13 over then we have to calculate module of 80 balls then this expression is use $f = $balls2 % 6; for module then i got 2 then i concate both values 13 and 2 with a decimal separator = 13.2(overs) ((float)$total_overs.'.'.$f;) you can test it on ex->43,44,94,110

Comment: if total balls delivered is 80 balls then first we have to make it divisible by 6 then we get 78 from ($balls -= $balls % 6;) then it will we divided by 6 then we get 13 means 13 over then we have to calculate module of 80 balls then this expression is use $f = $balls2 % 6; for module then i got 2 then i concate both values 13 and 2 with a decimal separator = 13.2(overs)  ((float)$total_overs.'.'.$f;)   you can test it on ex->43,44,94,110

Comment: in the post not in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Simple formula to calculate number of balls from overs bowled

```
=(FLOOR({overs})*6)+MOD({overs},FLOOR({overs}))*10
```

Example:
Overs = 96.2

Result:
Balls = 578

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple PHP condition for overcoming this problem. The method is Lengthy but working:-

```
 $ball__= 15;    
 $over=0;

          if($ball__>=6 && $ball__<12){
              $over+=1;
              if($ball__==6){$ball__=0;}
              if($ball__==7){$ball__=1;}
              if($ball__==8){$ball__=2;}
              if($ball__==9){$ball__=3;}
              if($ball__==10){$ball__=4;}
              if($ball__==11){$ball__=5;}
            }
            if($ball__>=12 && $ball__<18){
              $over+=2;
              if($ball__==12){$ball__=0;}
              if($ball__==13){$ball__=1;}
              if($ball__==14){$ball__=2;}
              if($ball__==15){$ball__=3;}
              if($ball__==16){$ball__=4;}
              if($ball__==17){$ball__=5;}
            }
            if($ball__>=18 && $ball__<24){
              $over+=3;
              if($ball__==18){$ball__=0;}
              if($ball__==19){$ball__=1;}
              if($ball__==20){$ball__=2;}
              if($ball__==21){$ball__=3;}
              if($ball__==22){$ball__=4;}
              if($ball__==23){$ball__=5;}
            }
            if($ball__>=24 && $ball__<30){
              $over+=4;
              if($ball__==24){$ball__=0;}
              if($ball__==25){$ball__=1;}
              if($ball__==26){$ball__=2;}
              if($ball__==27){$ball__=3;}
              if($ball__==28){$ball__=4;}
              if($ball__==29){$ball__=5;}
            }
            if($ball__>=30 && $ball__<36){
              $over+=5;
              if($ball__==30){$ball__=0;}
              if($ball__==31){$ball__=1;}
              if($ball__==32){$ball__=2;}
              if($ball__==33){$ball__=3;}
              if($ball__==34){$ball__=4;}
              if($ball__==35){$ball__=5;}
            }
//----and so on up to the number of balls you have to convert into overs. I have done this up to 6 overs(36 balls).

echo ($over.".".$ball__); to show results
```

`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

*Easy solution to convert balls into overs in golang*
package main

```
import "fmt"

func convertToOvers(totalBalls int) (int, int) {
    overs := totalBalls / 6
    remainingBalls := totalBalls % 6
    return overs, remainingBalls
}

func main() {
    var totalBalls int

    fmt.Print("Enter the total number of balls: ")
    fmt.Scanln(&totalBalls)

    overs, remainingBalls := convertToOvers(totalBalls)

    fmt.Printf("Number of overs: %d.%d\n", overs, remainingBalls)
}
```